# replace some characters on the names of variables in python

Tags: python

I would like to know why I cannot replace a character in the names of my variables? For example,

```py
df = pd.read_csv('mydf.csv')
df.columns
Index(['#house', '#var_c', '#var_v', '#othervar', '#pp', '#iv', '#iv%',
       '#income', '#blah'],
      dtype='object')
```

I would like to replace the '#' and '%' by ''. In other words, I would like to drop these characters. I tryied somthing like this

```py
df.columns.replace('#', '')
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Why I can not do this? And how I can find the solution (replace both '#' and '%' by '')?

Comment: `replace` is a string function; you tried to apply it to a df column.  Dig down one more reference level to the actual name.

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting, I'm on my phone.  Try something like: df.columns = [i.replace('#', '') for i in df.columns]  And then the same for %.  I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but this will get you there.

Comment: `df.columns.str.replace('#', '')` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df = df.rename(mapper=lambda c: c.strip("%#"), axis='columns')
print(df.columns)
```

**Output**

```
Index(['house', 'var_c', 'var_v', 'othervar', 'pp', 'iv', 'iv', 'income',
       'blah'], dtype='object')
```

If you need to replace by multiple characters, you could use a regex:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[], columns=['#house', '#var_c', '#var_v', '#othervar', '#pp', '#iv', '#iv%',
       '#income', '#blah'])

df = df.rename(mapper=lambda c: re.sub('[#%]', '$', c), axis='columns')
print(df.columns)
```

**Output**

```
Index(['$house', '$var_c', '$var_v', '$othervar', '$pp', '$iv', '$iv$',
       '$income', '$blah'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I wish I had the option to replace with another character. For example, suppose I want to replace "#" AND "%"  BY "$".

Comment: @Fam Updated the answer.